# [OData][ASP.NET] Delta type request not working with Guid and Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, odata

I need your help about OData, expecially about Delta request.

In my controller extend of ODataController:

```
[HttpPatch("{key}/edit")]
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public IActionResult PostEdit(Guid key, Delta<Bike> request)
    {
        Bike p = _bikeRespository.Get(key);
        if (request == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("unable to find id");
        request.Patch(p);
        _bikeRespository.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(p);
    }
```

So I do the request with my postman

url : http://localhost:5001/api/Bike/f6e4d714-debc-4df8-827d-0c80f50944ee/edit

Request Body:

```
{"Name": "YZR M1123",
"productid":"58d6c929-258c-44d9-b0e7-40907e638190",
"Price": 21000,
"IsSecond" : true }
```

Response body:

```
{"id": "f6e4d714-debc-4df8-827d-0c80f50944ee",
"name": "YZR M1123",
"productId": "e541382f-6143-41ba-b954-1a2b2f5791f6",
"price": 50000000,
"isSecond": true,
"dateRelease": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
```

`IsSecond` and Name value was changed, but `productId` and price isn't

Bike class like this

```
public class Bike : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Name { set; get; }

    public Guid productId { set; get; }

    public int Price { set; get; }

    public bool IsSecond { set; get; }

    public DateTime DateRelease { set; get; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(productId))]
    public Product Product { set; get; }

}
```

Is there something wrong or lacking??

Comment: The capitalization of the variable names is very inconsistent, could that be the issue?

Comment: at first I thought so, but after I changed it it was still the same.

Comment: Any luck getting this resolved? I am seeing the same issue with Guids and also Enums